# how extract text from pdf using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox

Is there a way to get text that exist inside the border of specific color let say "red".
is it possible to all the text that exist in side "red" border box from pdf using c#. i had googled it but i did not found anyway to get text with style format from pdf.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from PDFs in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116440/extracting-text-from-pdfs-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't parse a PDF like you do HTML.  I think @Joe Irby has the best solution... find a third-party option.  But it won't be easy.

Comment: The OP already tagged his question [tag:pdfbox] which is for a third-party library for PDF handling. I think he effectively asks how to implement his task using PDF Box.

Comment: Muhammad, how are those red border boxes drawn? There are numerous ways to do so in PDFs. Creating a solution for all those ways in a single answer is too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: Did you try ExtractTextByArea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not simple, unfortunately.  Usually, when programmers need to write code that can parse text out of PDF files (what you are trying to do), they use third-party code libraries that other people wrote specifically for manipulating PDFs.  In the C# world, there are a few options for well-known PDF manipulation libraries, but the ones that are easiest to use are not free.  I've personally had good results using a library called iTextSharp, but it is not free.

Comment: The OP already tagged his question [tag:pdfbox] which is for a third-party library for PDF handling. I think he effectively asks how to implement his task using PDF Box, not how to do it without a library.